# Examining a solution of a differential equation without knowing the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

The differential equation is given by $$\dot x=-x \cos x$$ with $x(0)=x_0\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Now I need to show that for each choice of $x_0$ the domain of the solution $x: I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is $\mathbb{R}$, so $I=\mathbb{R}$.
In addition to that I need to show that $x$ is strictly monotonically decreasing and converges for $t\to-\infty$ and $t\to\infty$ respectively to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0$ respectively.
The hint is not to find the explicit solution of the differential equation but to examine the function $x$ qualitativly.

By using the help below I managed to show all these statements about $x$ (little questions remain).

But if there aren't any restrictions for $x_0$, what can I say about $x$ and its maximality?
I think there are six cases (apart from the case above):
$1)~x_0\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},0)\Rightarrow x<0 \wedge \cos(x)>0 \Rightarrow \dot x>0$
$2)~x_0\in(-\frac{(4k-1)\pi}{2},-\frac{(4k-3)\pi}{2}),k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}\Rightarrow x<0 \wedge \cos(x)<0\Rightarrow \dot x<0 $
$3)~x_0\in(-\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2},-\frac{(4k-1)\pi}{2}),k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}\Rightarrow x<0 \wedge \cos(x)>0 \Rightarrow \dot x>0$
$4)~x_0\in(\frac{(4k-3)\pi}{2},\frac{(4k-1)\pi}{2}),k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}\Rightarrow x>0 \wedge \cos(x)<0\Rightarrow \dot x>0  $
$5)~x_0\in(\frac{(4k-1)\pi}{2},\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2}),k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}\Rightarrow x>0 \wedge \cos(x)>0 \Rightarrow \dot x<0 $
$6)~x_0=\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2}, k\in\mathbb{Z}$ or $x_0=0\Rightarrow \dot x\equiv 0 \Rightarrow x\equiv x_0$.

Is it possible to get the same properties in these six cases as in the case above ($I=\mathbb{R}$ and the convergence of $x$ to the limits of the interval in which $x_0$ lies)?

Comment: For me, for these problems it REALLY helps to graph the RHS.

Comment: You may try to prove that $x(t)\in(0,\pi/2)$ for all $t$ in the maximal interval of existence of $x$. Then, it will yield $I=\mathbb{R}$ and $x$ is strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

The equation satisfies the conditions that guarantee existence and uniqueness of solution. $x(t)=\pi/2$ and $x(t)=0$ are constant solutions. If $x(0)\in(0,\pi/2)$, by uniqueness of solution it must be that
$$
0<x(t)<\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
for all $t$ for which thwe solution is defined. This implies that the solution is global, that is, it is defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: May as well add that $x=0$ is also a constant solution, which proves the limits.

Comment: Right. I just thought of the zeros of $\cos x$. Will modify the answer.

Comment: How do I see that $0<x(t)<\frac{\pi}{2}$ implies that the solution is global? Could you give me a hint? @Julián Aguirre

Comment: Local existence theorem guarantees a solution on some interval $I$. Put $\tau = \sup I$, the solution can be extended to $\tau$ (if not already defined there) by taking limit. If the solution is bounded, again by the local existence theorem the solution can be extended beyond $\tau$ (with $x(\tau)$ being the new initial condition). Now suppose a solution on $I$ cannot be extended beyond $I$. Then by the arguments above it cannot be bounded.

Comment: The solution either is global or blows up in finite time. Since it remains bounded on any interval of existence, it cannot blow up.